Genymotion is stuck on the loading screen can;t get past it
I am trying to run a unity game on genymotion android emulator so I can test on android 13 on my HP probook 6460b windows 10 which uses an Intel(R) HD 3000 display adapter for it's display driver but it has been futile so far because I keep staying at the splash screen.
I have tried running genymotion as an administrator I have switched from the default SDK it comes with to the one I have uninstalled and reinstalled too I cleared it's cache I have done practically everything I have being suggested to do including manually connecting ADB to it, it still did not work please any help will be appreciated or if you know any other emulator that runs outside of android studio that can allow me run android 14 I would really love to hear
